# How can I retrieve or calculate estimated time remaining in the current epoch?

Tags: time, epoch

I'm using the solana_client crate, but looking at the JSON RPC API I also don't see any way to retrieve the time remaining in the current epoch.

Is this because where this is displayed it is a calculated estimate? If so, I'm curious how to calculate this.

My guess is that you get the time for a recent slot and multiply that by the slots remaining in the current epoch, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've mostly got it right -- although slots are targeted at 400ms, that often isn't the case, so the tools adapt to the average block time in order to estimate how much longer the epoch will go.

Your best bet is to read through the CLI code which processes `solana epoch-info`: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/a7e4df5d6e62b877aa0ec4bfcf5cef9317c2cb6d/cli/src/cluster_query.rs#L1102

And the part that estimates: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/a7e4df5d6e62b877aa0ec4bfcf5cef9317c2cb6d/cli-output/src/cli_output.rs#L315

Answer (score 1):

After inspecting the frontpage on https://explorer.solana.com/ I can see that they call getEpochInfo quite often to calculate the remaining epoch time exactly as you have described.